# Unable to connect with MongoDB using Java Driver on Heroku

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, heroku, nullpointerexception

I am building a web application with Java and MongoDB on Heroku. I learnt this project from [here](https://blog.openshift.com/developing-single-page-web-applications-using-java-8-spark-mongodb-and-angularjs/). I have been kept trying for two days.

I use `3.2.2 mongo-java-driver` and `3.5.1 maven-compiler-plugin`

This is in my `Main` class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MongoException, UnknownHostException, Exception {
    MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI(System.getenv("MONGOHQ_URL"));
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);

    String dbname = uri.getDatabase();

    //mongoClient.setWriteConcern(WriteConcern.JOURNALED);
    DB db = mongoClient.getDB(dbname);

    staticFileLocation("/public");
    new TodoResource(new TodoService(db));

    MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(uri.getUsername(),dbname,uri.getPassword());
    MongoClientOptions mongoClientOptions = MongoClientOptions.builder().build();
}
```

And I got this error:

```
1:38:42 AM web.1 | Exception in thread "main"
1:38:42 AM web.1 | java.lang.NullPointerException
1:38:42 AM web.1 | at com.mongodb.MongoClientURI.<init>   (MongoClientURI.java:174…
1:38:42 AM web.1 | at com.mongodb.MongoClientURI.<init> (MongoClientURI.java:159…
1:38:42 AM web.1 | at Main.main(Main.java:32)
```

It's NullPointerException, so I tried to replace `MONGOHQ_URL` by `mongodb://user:passwd@host1:port1,host2:port2/dbname`, and I also tried to use *mLab MongoDB* on Heroku, but the same error:

```
11:17:05 AM web.1 |  SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
11:17:05 AM web.1 |  SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/zhugejunwei/full-sta…
11:17:05 AM web.1 |  SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/zhugejunwei/full-sta…
11:17:05 AM web.1 |  SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings …
11:17:05 AM web.1 |  SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerF…
11:17:05 AM web.1 |  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
11:17:05 AM web.1 |     at com.mongodb.ConnectionString.<init>(ConnectionString.java…
11:17:05 AM web.1 |     at com.mongodb.MongoClientURI.<init>(MongoClientURI.java:176…
11:17:05 AM web.1 |     at com.mongodb.MongoClientURI.<init>(MongoClientURI.java:158…
11:17:05 AM web.1 |     at Main.main(Main.java:28)
```

From the [original version](https://blog.openshift.com/developing-single-page-web-applications-using-java-8-spark-mongodb-and-angularjs/) to my current version, I really tried a lot, and I just want to make it runnable on Heroku to learn this project in another way.

When I learnt another tutorial, the code below is ok, but I don't know why it doesn't work in this project.

```
MongoURI mongoURI = new MongoURI(System.getenv("MONGOHQ_URL"));
//get connected
DB db = mongoURI.connectDB();
mongoURI.getPassword());
MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(mongoURI.getUsername(), mongoURI.getDatabase(), mongoURI.getPassword());
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(), Arrays.asList(credential));
```

I also opened an issue on [github](https://github.com/infsci2560sp16/full-stack-web-project-zhugejunwei/issues/2) and on [jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-2158)

Please help me with this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you connect to your mongo database via command line ?

Comment: @vincent Yes, I can connect to mongolab via command line, and I can create user and create collections via command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried for more than 40 hours, and finally get it worked.

I changed a lot. Here are something I think is important:

First, it seems I cannot use `DB db = mongoURI.connectDB();`, maybe because of the **3.2.2 java-driver version** or because of the **MongoDB version** on Heroku. When I use "`MongoDatabase`" instead of "`DB`", **some errors** disappeared, but still cannot run the project. Because I have to changed a lot in my project wherever used "DB", and this is very difficult to change from `DB` to `MongoDatabase`.

I realized that I can use `DB` in **2.7.2**, so I changed all the syntaxes related to the *mongo-java-driver* version. But again, errors disappeared, I cannot run the project. However, at this time, it seems most errors disappeared. One more error showed that another process is running on the same port. I killed that process. Now all errors gone. When I run it, I cannot open it on Heroku, but on port 4567. This is weird, because the default port for Heroku is 5000, and 4567 is the default port for Jetty, which is a embedded server for Java application. I added this piece of code, and it finally worked.

```
port(Integer.valueOf(System.getenv("PORT")));
```

Thanks to my professor and thanks to all the people that helped me.